# How to use completionHandler of application performFetchWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios7, background-process

In the new iOS 7 SDK, you can perform background fetches, by implementing `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` (http://bit.ly/15ofOx8).

They say you are supposed to execute completionHandler when you are done. When exactly is that?

My performFetch looks like this:

```
NSString *result = [super.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"loadFeeds();"];
```

`loadFeeds` is a JavaScript function in a WebView, that makes an AJAX call. Which means it's probably going to go to another thread and loose the `completionHandler`. How can I execute `completionHandler` when the Ajax call is done?

I thought about using UIWebView's `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` to catch a custom URL, but by then I have completely lost `completionHandler`.

Comment: do you have any callback method in native code which will get triggered when the AJAX request is done?

Comment: I don't. But like I said I though of using this technique (http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/) to make an Obj-C call when the Ajax is done.

Comment: Why would you lose the completionHandler? Can't you just save it as a property or something?

Comment: The thing is, I thought of saving it as a property, but then if multiple calls are made to performFetch by the iOS I think there will be problems. I think I heard soemthing about it from Apple.

Comment: Well, can't you just not do anything if you receive another performFetch and completionHandler has already been registered (meaning that you're still waiting for the AJAX call to complete)?

Comment: If you aren't calling the completionHandler in time (your app has 30s) your app is getting killed by iOS. This means performFetchWithCompletionHandler is called only once until you either call the handler in your code or get killed by iOS.

Saving it in an ivar is the way to go, just save it and called it when your webview is done.

Comment: Are you sure your webview can perform the fetch while in background? 'cause I wasn't able to make it works in my project so maybe could also have the same issue...